# How to open application just by typing server name?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver, mod-alias

I have a server which is having several applications. lets say server is abc.corp.com it is having application xyz pqr mno etc. Today the applications are accessed as

abc.corp.com/xyz
abc.corp.com/pqr
abc.corp.com/mno

Out of these i want application xyz to open just by typing abc.corp.com   and rest of the applications opening normally.

My Server is apache and i am having php applications inside it. I have read alias can help me do that. But how exactly i can achieve it is not clear.

Comment: I didnt get you exactly, what do you mean by bookmarks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put this code in **index.php** of `abc.corp.com` (http://abc.corp.com/**index.php** position)

```
<?php
header location('http://abc.corp.com/xyz');
die();
?>
```